# How to get selected value from drop-down which is disabled in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

There is a drop-down on my screen which shows some selected value and it is disabled.
I need the selected value from the drop-down list to put some assertions in Selenium.

How to get the selected value when drop-down is disbaled?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0AUQ.png)

I tried using below code:

```
Select billCycle = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[contains(@id,'BILL_CYC_CD')]")));
String billCycleValue = billCycle.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
```

But I am getting below exception:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=110.0.5481.178)
```

Answer (score 1):

### getFirstSelectedOption()

[*`getFirstSelectedOption()`*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html#getFirstSelectedOption()) returns the first selected option in this select tag (or the currently selected option in a normal select).

---

### This usecase

To print the selected value from the drop-down list you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *cssSelector* and *`id`* attribute:

  ```
  WebElement billCycle = new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("select#BILL_CYC_CD")))).getFirstSelectedOption();
  System.out.println(billCycle.getText());
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *`name`* attribute:

  ```
  WebElement billCycle = new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//[@name='BILL_CYC_CD']")))).getFirstSelectedOption();
  System.out.println(billCycle.getText());
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently trying to get first option from disabled select.

Try instead getting all of the options from dropdown:

```
List<String> billCycleValues = billCycle.getOptions();
```